# vectorise pandas: extract multiple dataframes and concat together

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I need to extract dataframes from json data stored in every row of initial dataframe and concat them all together. Currently it works for me over iteration  and takes ages.

Input data is dataframe, containing JSON dictionaries:

```
print(json_table)

         json_responce   timestamp              request
27487   {'explore_tabs.. 2019-07-02 02:05:25    Lisboa, Portugal
27488   {'explore_tabs.. 2019-07-02 02:05:27    Ribeira, Portugal
```

The json_responce field is being unwraped to dataframe:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from ast import literal_eval

json = literal_eval(json_table.loc[0,'json_responce'])
df_normalized = json_normalize(json['explore_tabs'][0]['sections'][0] 
['listings'])
```

which gives a nice unwrapped dataframe for each row of the initial df

Having 27000 rows of json containing df, I iterate over initial df, which creates new df at every step and concat's to the final_df, to concat all the data together:

```
def unwrap_json_and_concat(json_table):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in json_table.index:
        row = literal_eval(json_table.loc[i,'json_responce'])
        df = json_normalize(row['explore_tabs'][0]['sections'] 
     [0]['listings'])
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df,df])
    return final_df
```

As expected, that takes ages to iterate over, with significant slowing towards the end of calculation  due to  the increasing size of the final_df.

I know how to create functions for `apply`, but I  believe  it will  not give much perfomance either, due to  the fact, that new dataframe is being created every row anyways.

How  to vectorize this calculation?
Thank you!

Comment: It's much better to create a list of small dataframes and concatenate them all in one go at the end.

Comment: not quite a vectorisation, but still a dramatic shift in perfomance, thank you!